# android google map v2 - inflate map fragment layout take too long and results in lagging

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

As title said, **it takes too long to inflate the layout containing a google map fragment** (around 4xx ms) and results in a lagging. How to solve this problem?

fragment_google.map.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

MapFragment

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    //this method consumes 4xx ms to done
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map, container, false);
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: It May be because of your slow internet connection.

Comment: It may be for internet connection but you can also try to extend FragmentActivity by replacing Fragment.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee Do you get any kind of error or warning in your logcat ?

Comment: How can I will get this, because it's not my question @GrlsHu :)

Comment: What I do is: I press a button in Fragment A, then go to MyMapFragment. But as the long time loading of onCreateView() method, the button freeze ~0.4 sec and then show MyMapFragment.

Comment: @GrIsHu no errors in logcat

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee Sorry typo mistake :)

Comment: This can be anything from a `Thread.sleep(400);` in your `onClick` to network code. You are not posting relevant parts of the code. Also be aware, you should not put fragments inside other fragment's layout. See the official rules: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments